# How to deal with one time execution of "code piece" or method?

Tags: java, performance

I come across this kind of a situation a lot.

```
class A{
  public static boolean flag = true;

  public void method(){
    // calls method in class B
    B b = new B();
    while(someCondition){
      b.method();
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
class B{

    public void method(){
      if(A.flag){
        // Read all data from a flat file and store it in HashMAp/ArrayList etc 
        //only for the first time
        A.flag = false;
      }
      // Manipulate the data
   }
}
```

I seem to be running into this type of situation quite often in completely different situations.

Is this how it is normally dealt with? I feel a bit silly and unnatural using static variables and if statements to resolve the issue.

In this case, I don't want to cause an overhead by reading data every time the method is executed.

Comment: That's not even valid java code. Please put some effort in your question. Also, pass the flag as a parameter to B.

Comment: Why do you have to do it like this? Can't you just call the data processing code once without that if?

Comment: @Tudor: Did you mean that I should put the data processing code in class A ? Actually the data processing code has dependents in class B, so it cannot be moved there. This  is a simplistic model

Comment: No, no it's ok I just misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need the *Singleton Pattern*. Figure out what data `B` needs to load upon its first use, and package that into a separate class that gets used as a singleton instance. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) for more information on how to implement the singleton pattern in Java.

Following this pattern, you can avoid the need for checking a flag every time your `method` is called, and you can simultaneously avoid any threading issues (if there are any).

Comment: Nice use of design principals. Might be overkill depending on the situation (not a critique) so asker should assess situation

Comment: Although threading must be taken into account WRT creating the instance / getting the instance and may cause blocking while first instance is being created.

Comment: @JohnB: Using the correct code pattern (see my link), the JVM can handle the threading. And blocking on the first instance is almost undoubtedly better than doing all the work twice, and making each thread block until it has built its own version of the necessary elements. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Yes, I using quartz to run jobs (class A method is actually executeInternal Method). There are multiple threads running the code. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Had not seen the wrapper class implementation before. VERY COOL! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As John B pointed out, a simple check for `null` should be enough rather than using a flag.  If thread safety becomes an issue, you might also look into Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) and [Suppliers.memoize()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize%28com.google.common.base.Supplier%29) for these types of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reading an external flag to determine if the data has already been stored, why not check the data store to see if it is populated? Or if the data store is expensive (DB) use a local static variable rather than one in a different class.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check if the list/map that stores your data has been initialised by a previous call

```
class A {

  public void method() {
    B b = new B();
    while (someCondition) {
      b.method();
    }
  }
}

class B {

  private List myList;

  public void method() {
    if (myList == null) {
      // Read all data from a flat file and store it in myList
    } 
    // manipulate the data

  }
}
```